# How do I make sure that the user enters a number between 0 and 10 only?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have made an array with all my subjects called subjectName. The goal of this code is to make sure that the user only enters valid numbers (between 1.0 and 10.0). but I don't know how to do that. I created an if statement and make it return if the subjectname isn't between 0 and 10 but that doesn't work. I am not sure how I can tackle this.

EDIT: subjectName are the names of each subject so its a String. subjectGrade is a double. BOTH ARE ARRAYS. Forgot to mention that.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subjectName.length; i++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("What is your grade for: " + subjectName[i] + "? ");
            subjectGrade[i] = input.nextDouble();

            if ( subjectGrade[i] < 0.0 || subjectGrade[i] > 10.0) {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: What are the types of `subjectName`, `invoer`, `vakCijfers`?

Comment: You need a number 1-10 or 0-10? I'm not sure it matters but I'm confused

Comment: oh second let me change it

Comment: subjectName are the names of each subject so its a String. subjectGrade is a double.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? It doesn't `return`?

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean by doesn't work? On what input did you try?

Comment: I mean it doesn't return to the question ''What is your grade the subjectname[i]". When they enter an invalid number that isn't between 0 and 10. It just goes to the next subject

Comment: Oh... Then the way you asked it is wrong... You should've asked "how can I..." because this code doesn't seem like it is meant to repeat until correct answer...

Comment: So if you input -1.0 this code doesn't `return`.?

Comment: @Neo yup, I realized that. Do you perhaps know how I can repeat until they correctly answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `while` loop. Ask the question while the grade is invalid.

```
while(subjectGrade[i] < 0.0 || subjectGrade[i] > 10.0)
{
    System.out.print("What is your grade for: " + subjectName[i] + "? ");
    subjectGrade[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
```

(Goes instead of the `if`)

Anyway, your mistake is that the `return` statement doesn't repeats last command or anything. It returns a value from a function...

Comment: Your'e welcome. Next time be careful to write your question clearly. Also, it'll be nice if you marked my answer as correct:)

Comment: Btw can I ask you another question or do I need to make a whole new topic?

Comment: @TonyStark You can ask

Comment: I have another array called subjectPoints. For each subject you will receive points if your grade is greater is than 5,5. I need to make another for loop where I add those when the grade is greater than or equal to 5.5. Otherwise your points are 0.

Comment: this is the code:  for (int i = 0; i < subjectGrade.length; i++) {
            if ( vakCijfers[i] > 5.5) {
              subjectTotal += subjectGrade[i];
            }
            else {
                subjectGrade[i] = 0;
            }

Comment: @TonyStark If I understood right, why won't you replace `subjectTotal` with `subjectPoints[i]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(subjectGrade[i] < 0.0 || subjectGrade[i] > 10.0) {
    i--; // subract one so we doesn't skip the one student who made incorrect input
    // you can put return or continue here, but not necessary
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only increase i when the input is valid

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < subjectName.length; ) {

    System.out.print("What is your grade for: " + subjectName[i] + "? ");
    double grade = input.nextDouble();
    if ( grade > 0.0 && grade < 10.0) {
        studentGrade[i++] = grade;
    }
    // else, loop repeats with same value of 'i'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `if` there is a wrong variable. It should be `vakCijfers[i]`, right?

```
if ( vakCijfers[i] < 0.0 || vakCijfers[i] > 10.0) {
```

Comment: yeah I just changed it. Sorry

Comment: subjectName are the names of each subject so its a String. subjectGrade is a double. Both are arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to repat until correct answer use:

```
do{
  subjectGrade[i] = input.nextDouble();
}while(!isValid(subjectGrade[i]);
```

and `isValid(double Grade)` checks the validity condition.